# Passing a variable to sed inside for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, sed, increment

I have a for loop written in a script like so:

```
for((i=0;i<${#hours[@]})); do
    dates=("$(last | egrep -v "reboot|wtmp|^$" | sort | tr -s " " | sed "$i q;d" | cut -f5-7 -d' ')")
done
```

If I simply execute the command assigned to `dates` in the terminal, replacing `$i` (inside the sed command) by a number (0,1,2...), it returns me exactly what I want, which is, for instance `Nov 15 23:15`.

However, when inside the `for` loop, I seem to have a problem with the sed command not incrementing `$i`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to append to the array for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: I suggest to replace `i=0` by `i=1`.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, I am trying to append a date with each iteration.

Comment: @Cyrus That doesn't fix it, though I think I need to start at 1.

Comment: `+=` should be used instead of `=` within the loop to append each item. That said, it would be better for you to show us a sample of your input and your desired output, as there's likely to be a much simpler way to get what you want

Comment: @TomFenech Wow, thank you very much, that has fixed it. I feel somewhat blind now. Bash drives me crazy sometimes :P

Comment: @Re4XN, don't edit your question to invalidate the comments.  That's not how a Question-and-Answer site works, and it's then no help to others with the same problem.  I've summarised the comments as an answer, which you can "accept" to indicate that it helped you.  And I've rolled back your question to one that actually demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you never change `i`.  You should probably update it in the third part of your `for` statement:

```
for((i=0;i<${#hours[@]};++i)); do
#                       ^^^ here
```